# Determine the type of singularities of $f(z)$

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $f(z)=\dfrac{(z-1)^2(z+3)}{1-\sin(\frac{\pi z}{2})}$. Determine which kind of isolated singularities it has and the location of this singularities.

The singularities  are $z=1+4k$. Now I first want to find the order of the zeros. I'm stuck because substituiting $z=1+4k$ in $f(z)$ and look when the $n$th derivate isn't equal to 0 doesn't work. Why is it allowed to look at the function $\frac{1}{1-\sin(\frac{\pi z}{2})}$?
And can somebody help me with determining the other types and places of singularities of $f(z)$?

Comment: if you take second derivatives of numerator and denominator, then you do not get zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$z_{k} = 4k +1 $ are zeros of  the second order of the denominator, but $z = 1 $ and $z = -3 $ are also zeros of the numerator.

So we have that $4k + 1 \neq 1, -3$ are poles of the second order, $-3$ is a pole of the first order and $1$ is not a singularity, i.e. is a removable singularity.

Infact, in the case of $1$, $\exists$ a function $h(z)$ analytic in $1$ with $1-sin(\frac{\pi z}{2}) = (z-1)^{2}h(z)$ and $h(1) \neq 0 $ because $1$ is a zero of the second order, so $$\frac{(z-1)^{2}(z+3)}{1-sin(\frac{\pi z}{2})} =\frac{(z-1)^{2}(z+3)}{(z-1)^{2}h(z)} = \frac{(z+3)}{h(z)}  $$ and this means that $1$ is a removable singularity.

The case $z = -3 $ and $z = 4k +1 \neq 1, -3 $ is analogous.

Then you have to study the behaviour of $f$ in $\infty$ by studying the behaviour in $0$ of $g(z) = f(\frac{1}{z})$.

Comment: Can you explain: So we have that 4k+1≠1,−3 are poles of the second order, −3 is a pole of the first order and 1 is not a singularity, i.e. is a removable singularity?

Comment: It's $z+3$, not $z-3$.